# What are these things called / for? <something("string")>

Tags: vb.net

When I was writing a program that manipulated Active Directory, I found I needed to extend the `GroupPrincipal` class, and found some code that told me how to do this.

```vb
<DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")>
<DirectoryObjectClass("group")>
Public Class GroupPrincipalEx
    Inherits DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal

    Public Sub New(context As PrincipalContext)
        MyBase.New(context)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(context As PrincipalContext, samAccountName As String)
    ...
```

What are the parts in angle-brackets called? What are they for? Where can I learn more about them.

I'm not asking about something specific to this case, my program works just fine. I just don't know what this language feature is, or does, or when to use it in future cases.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/

Comment: Ahh, thank you jonrsharpe.  Not knowing what they were called, I was having a hard time googleing them.

Searches for brackets or things like vb.net <soemthing>  yielded useless results.

Comment: I just searched for "Visual Basic angle brackets".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/). Attributes can be evaluated by using [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection).

**Attributes**

> Attributes provide a powerful method of associating metadata, or
>   declarative information, with code (assemblies, types, methods,
>   properties, and so forth). After an attribute is associated with a
>   program entity, the attribute can be queried at run time by using a
>   technique called reflection.

**Reflection**

> The classes in the System.Reflection namespace, together with
>   System.Type, enable you to obtain information about loaded assemblies
>   and the types defined within them, such as classes, interfaces, and
>   value types. You can also use reflection to create type instances at
>   run time, and to invoke and access them.